# Fail safe "multitasking" to restore gamestate in iOS game?

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

With iOS "multitasking" a running app's state is saved when the user starts another app, and in theory when the user restarts the saved app it should start exactly where it was stopped before.

However, I have noticed that some games does not always recover their previous state, and instead reloads from the beginning. For example Bloons TD. Sometimes when I am in the middle of a game and switches back and forth between apps I will get back to where I was, sometimes the game restarts. It's not clear to me why it restarts sometimes but not always.

I am making an opengl based game, and I'd like to know if there is a way to ensure the game state is *always* saved properly? What I want to avoid is to make a game save/load system myself, if possible.

Comment: The OS does not save your state. It just suspends you. If your app resumes without getting killed, then it will have lost nothing. But if the app is killed in the background (due to memory pressure, or the OS restarting) then it's responsible for restoring whatever state it decided to save.

Comment: Oh, I see.. That clears up quite a bit. I could never reproduce the app getting killed issue which I have observed before, and it's simply because my game is not spending more than the available RAM. I thought iOS was smarter than this, all the reviews talks about how great the multitasking and that iOS saves the app in the background, but in fact the apps are doing all the hard work themselves. Seems no way around making a save/load game system then...

Comment: The OS cannot be expected to save the contents of your memory space and restore it past application kills. But you can use the `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` method to save whatever state you want, which you can then restore upon app launch if present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the methods:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

in the `AppDelegate` so that if the app enters the background, save the current game state, and if the game becomes active again, load the current game state. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Note, if the application becomes active, you don't need to load the current state since it's already loaded (you were merely suspended). Only if your app is launching anew do you need to check for and load current state.